# concatenating variables inside linux commands in perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I need to use a system command (`grep`) which has a variable concatenated with a string as the regex to search a file.
Is it possible to concatenate a regex for `grep` between a variable and string in Perl??

I have tried using the `.` operator but it doesn't work.

```
if(`grep -e "$fubname._early_exit_indicator = 1" $golden_path/early_exit_information.tsv`){
    print "-D- The golden data indicates early exit should occur\n";
    $golden_early_exit_indicator=1;
}
```

Expected to match the regex, `"$fubname._early_exit_indicator = 1"` but it doesn't match as required.
The expected result should be:
`-D- The golden data indicates early exit should occur`
But in the present code, it doesn't print this.

Output link: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N0SaZ-r3bYPlljKUgTOH5AbxCAaHw7zD)

Comment: Here, $fubname is my variable, and I am trying to concatenate the _early_exit_indicator string to it.

Comment: Use `${fubname}_early_exit_indicator`

Comment: [Read the fine manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldata.pod#Scalar-value-constructors): "As in some shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces to disambiguate it from following alphanumerics (and underscores)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.` operator is not recognized as an operator inside quotes. Dot operators are use *between* strings, not *inside* strings. Using the dot inside a string, inserts it literally. This literal dot in the pattern, causes the `grep` command in your code to fail.

Also note that inside quotes, Perl tries to interpolates variable using certain identifier parsing rules.
See [`perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for the different types of quoting that are used in Perl, and see [`perldoc perldata`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for information about the identifier parsing rules.

In summary, in order to interpolate the variable `$fubname` in the backticks argument, use

```
"${fubname}_early_exit_indicator = 1"
```

Note that we need braces around the identifier, since the following underscore is a valid identifier character. (To the contrary a literal dot is not a valid identifier character, so if following character was a literal dot, you would not need the braces around the identifier.)

Comment: Another way is to escape the string for separating it from the variable name: `"$fubname\_early_exit_indicator = 1"`

Answer (score -1):

The . operator will not work inside the quotes. use something like this-

if(`grep -e "${fubname}_early_exit_indicator = 1" ...

I hope this works